# Populating row of dates in cells depending on month picked

Tags: excel, dropdown, populate

I have a sheet where the user is supposed to pick a Month-Name from a dropdown in one cell A2. I want a formula that populates the dates in the row depending on the month picked. Please me in this case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An example of output please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you may try this :

[image]

• If you are using `MS365` then use

```
=SEQUENCE(DAY(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(B2 &0)+1, 1) -1),,DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(B2&1),1))
```

• if not then try the one below,

```
=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(B2&1),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&DAY(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(B2&0)+1,1)-1))))
```

---

Edit: Since OP is using Excel 2013, may try this out:

[image]

• Formula used in cell `E4`

```
=IF(ROWS(E$4:E4)>DAY(EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH($D$4&1),1),0)),
"",DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH($D$4&1),ROW(A1)))
```

Comment: I Am using Office 2013 and its worked for me what I want. bundle of thanks again Sir

Comment: Please can you tell me how to remove the extra date from the cell in the column when I select "Feb"

Comment: Extra date means, also since you are using Office 2013, you need to drag down the formula, so there is no need for remove you drag the formula till the number of cells you need

Comment: Please see the output picture Below.

Comment: Ok give few minutes I am updating it

Comment: Or, you can use this it is less Verbose, : `=IF(ROWS(D$4:D4)>DAY(EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH($B$2&1),1),0)),"",DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH($B$2&1),ROW(A1)))`

Comment: Glad to know it worked for you =)

Comment: Sir can I clear the formula from the rest of the cells when I select "February" or Months which have less than 31

Comment: @InfomediaPlus yes, why not, but when its other month you need to fill down again.

Comment: ok, sir, I create a Combobox in userform and run this code with combobox_change. so please guide me to clear non-visible cells

Comment: @InfomediaPlus for this you need to create a new query post. One query per post. Initial query of yours was to fill dates as per month name which is sorted. Can you create a new query please.

Comment: Glad it worked for you =)